# Restify set method like in Express

Tags: node.js, api, rest, restify

In Express 4.0, after declaring the server I do the following to set a server-wide variable...

```
var app = express();
app.set('foo', 'bar');
```

I don't see a method like that in Restify's documentation, so I'm just declaring an object inside the server that holds my variables.

Is that correct? Is there a better way to do this in Restify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like that would work, but why not just create a module to hold your variables? Create a file named vars.js somewhere appropriate and make it like this:

```
module.exports = {
    my_var: 2112,
    other_var: 'signals'
}
```

Then wherever you need access to those variable just

```
var all_vars = require('./path/to/var.js');
```

and you'll have them.

Comment: I ended up doing just that and also passing some vars as environment variables, so I make sure I don't have any passwords hardcoded in the app.